# Neural network training: Early stopping vs. reducing the number of neurons/layers

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, overfitting

Assuming we have a regression task (1D-output, values between `0.0` and `1.0`) with 100 input dimensions and a classical MLP with one hidden layer.

When given 10000 training examples, a network with, for example, 50 neurons in the hidden layer has around 5000 trainable parameters and might overfit.

To avoid this, two (out of many) options are:

- apply early stopping (quit training when the validation loss no longer improves)
- reduce the model complexity (for example, only use 8 neurons in the hidden layer, thus having only around 800 trainable parameters).

Assuming training duration and model size are irrelevant, is there a consensus about which method of these two is to be preferred?

Does one method usually produce better results than the other?

Comment: Use regularisation instead of early stopping - it is more controllable.  Reducing model complexity is a bit of a blunt instrument as it can only be reduced in discrete steps (and it is quite difficult in practice to decide exactly when to stop).  The regularisation parameter(s) are on the other hand continuous.  Using a large neural network with regularisation is usually quite effective, but there are no guarantees.

Answer (score 2):

Of course this decision is a difficult one without having a good understanding of the `data`, difficulty of the problem, and also the network architechture characteristics (e.g., activation functions) that you are considering. But as a rule of thumb (which might be very bad), you can make a decision about this based the following heuristic.

Perform your early stopping and measure:

- Your `Training` set error rate
- Your `Development` set error rate (do not touch your `test` set! [reason](https://machinelearningmastery.com/data-leakage-machine-learning/)).

Consider the following steps in order of appearance:

1. If your `Training` error is high, then you stopped too early. Let it continue for a while.
2. If the `Training` error stays high after you continued training, you actually have a [high `bias`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff). Increase the complexity of your network.
3. If your `Training` error is okay and now is close to `optimal/bayes` (compared to `Development` error which is still relatively high at the current `epoch`), it means that your network had enough `complexity` to reach the "optimum" point but it had too much complexity, as your `Development` set has not reached that "optimal" point yet. This indicates that you need to reduce the complexity of your network (i.e., reduce #`nodes`).
4. If the alternative is true (i.e., `Training` error ~= `Development` error at the current `epoch`), then you are doing fine with `complexity`, so keep training your model with further epochs.

Note that you are making this decision at a certain `epoch`. Former or later `epochs` may present you a different story.

Finally, a no-brainer approach (which could be safer in my opinion) is that you can simply re-run the model training and follow each path (i.e., reducing #`node` vs. increasing #`epoch`) and then compare the performances. I think Andrew NG. has a [pretty good lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1N_PDHuJ6Q) on this.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

A straight-forward answer from Yoshua Bengio
[image]

Page 11 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5533

-> So use more neurons in combination with early stopping

I do not think these two things are equal.

Early stopping just stops you from over**training**, that is you train longer than necessary for a given set of hyperparameters,  which results in a decreased validation loss. You can always use early stopping, independelty of the choice of hyperparameters.

However, reducing the number of neurons is an actual change to the architectures.

Early stopping can help you estimate the best possible validation loss for a given choice of architecture. So you can for example compare Model A to Model B. Early stopping helps you to identify the best loss, and hence the best parameters, for each model. And you now can adequately compare Model A to Model B. But in order find a well-performing model you need to change, hyperparameters that change the optimizer and or the architecture.

We can see also that when we train with 10 neurons as shown in OPs answer, we also get degradation of performance

[image]

Comment: You state that early stopping is good for model evaluation. But, if the models are not sufficiently trained (due to early-stopping), how can we fairly evaluate model A vs. B (note that if we continue they might reach a better error)?

Comment: In the best case you set the patience of your early stopping component high enough so that it will not stop the training too early. But you make always the argument, lets say you train for 100 epochs maybe after the 101th epoch you will observe a huge decrease in loss

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the answers already given, I conducted a small experiment using the MNIST dataset:

- train/val split: 60000/10000
- input dimensions: 784
- hidden layers: 1
- output neurons: 10

The number of neurons in the hidden layer is what I used to adjust the model complexity.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds


def normalize_img(image, label):
    """Normalizes images: `uint8` -> `float32`."""
    return tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255., label


(ds_train, ds_test), ds_info = tfds.load(
    "mnist",
    split=["train", "test"],
    shuffle_files=True,
    as_supervised=True,
    with_info=True,
)

# 60000
ds_train = ds_train.map(normalize_img, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
ds_train = ds_train.cache()
ds_train = ds_train.shuffle(ds_info.splits["train"].num_examples)
ds_train = ds_train.batch(128)
ds_train = ds_train.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

# 10000
ds_test = ds_test.map(normalize_img, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
ds_test = ds_test.batch(128)
ds_test = ds_test.cache()
ds_test = ds_test.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

for hidden_layer in range(2, 21):
    # https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/keras_example
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer, activation='elu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
    ])
    model.compile(
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
        loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()],
    )
    model.summary()

    history = model.fit(ds_train, epochs=100, validation_data=ds_test)

    layers = [28 * 28, hidden_layer, 10]
    params = model.count_params()
    val_loss = history.history["val_loss"]
    min_val_loss = min(val_loss)
    min_val_loss_min_ep = np.argmin(val_loss)
    min_val_loss_max_ep = len(val_loss) - np.argmin(val_loss[::-1]) - 1

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    ax.plot(history.epoch, history.history["loss"], label="train")
    ax.plot(history.epoch, history.history["val_loss"], label="val")
    ax.set_title(f"{layers=}; {params=}; {min_val_loss=:8.6};\n{min_val_loss_min_ep=}; {min_val_loss_max_ep=}")
    ax.set_ylim([0, 1.2])
    plt.xlabel("epochs")
    plt.ylabel("loss")
    plt.legend(loc="upper center")
    plt.grid()
    fig.savefig(f"{hidden_layer:02d}.png")
```

Resulting learning curves: https://imgur.com/a/SskHmNC

Example with 10 hidden neurons (does not need early stopping):
[image: DrTXzFt]

Example with 19 hidden neurons (does need early stopping around epoch 20):
[image: XNskR9S]

Interpretation: From some number of neurons in the hidden layer upward, we need early stopping to get the best validation loss for these models.
While I was somewhat cheering for the fewer-neurons solution to win, in this experiment, the solutions with more neurons (and early stopping!) performed better, i.e., the best validation loss was significantly lower.

Comment: Beautiful experiment. Thanks. I wonder at what "complexity" level the switch happens. Could you please redo the analyses with increasing number of hidden nodes (i.e., one by one) and simply plot the best error in each configuration?

Comment: @Amin.A Thanks. The code does exactly that, i.e., it iterates over the number of neurons in the hidden layer from 2 to 20. The results of each iteration are [here](https://imgur.com/a/SskHmNC). And `min_val_loss` should be the value you're looking for.

Comment: I do not agree with the interpretation.
1. Usually, you use early stopping to end training when the validation loss does not improve rather than when it gets worse. So in the top experiment, early stopping should have kicked in. https://keras.io/api/callbacks/early_stopping/
2. You do not NEED early stopping, you can just decrease the learning rate for the second experiment.
3. You do not know what happens after 100 epochs, it can still increase its validation loss
I get what you want to say, but I would argue if you found hyper parameters (including the number of epochs) that work well,

Comment: then you do not need early stopping anyways, but early stopping can help you identify the best hyperparameters, like for example, the validation loss of experiments 1 and 2 look the same at the end of the 100 hundred epochs, using early stopping for both however would have resulted in you knowing that more neurons actually perform better.

Comment: @Janosch Thanks. In the experiment, I purposely did not actually implement early stopping to get the full graphs. From the graphs, one can deduce where it would have ended with early stopping being enabled. And I agree, instead of early stopping I can of course also just manually reduce the number of epochs to what gives a good validation loss. One could call this method "manual early stopping". ;-) The graphs end at epoch 100 because I wanted them to not be squeezed too much. It's an approximation for an "infinite" number of training epochs. But yeah, I should have shown more epochs.

Comment: Here are the graphs for 500 epochs ([11 n](https://i.imgur.com/VYY2MCf.png), [19 n](https://i.imgur.com/Chrse3w.png)). They show, that 11 Neurons also need to be stopped early, i.e. not being trained infinitely. However, reducing the number of neurons even further at some point leads to [a situation where more training no longer worsens the validation loss](https://i.imgur.com/gfketYL.png). So qualitatively, I think the conclusion holds, i.e. the results, at least in this experiment, of using more neurons (and stopping early) are better compared to using so few neurons with "infinite" epochs.